# zipfile: how to set a password for a Zipfile?

Tags: python, zip, python-zipfile

I have a zipfile in (sav.zip) and I'm trying to set a password for it:

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("sav.zip")
zf.setpassword("1234")
```

but I get a `TypeError: expected Bytes, got str`.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: Please read [the documentation for `ZipFile.setpassword()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword). It doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: try this `zf.setpassword(b"1234")`, basically password param should be bytes instead of string.

Comment: By "set a password" do you want to convert it to a password-protected zipfile, or is it already password-protected and you want to set the password for reading?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is not mentioned in the documentation, but on Python 3, the password should be `bytes`, not `str`. So:

```
zf.setpassword(b"1234")
```

Note that the password is *only* used for *reading*, not writing! See the docstring for `ZipFile.open` in Python 3.

The `ZipFile` class can read "pkzip 2.0" encryption, which is not considered very strong (it has [known weaknesses](http://delaat.net/rp/2014-2015/p57/presentation.pdf) [pdf]). That could probably be the reason that *writing* them is not currently (as of Python 2.7.13 and 3.6) implemented in Python.

*Note:* The protection afforded by a password on a zipfile might not very strong, depending on what you want to use it for. An attacker can e.g. *replace* a password-protected entry in a zipfile *without knowing the password*! See e.g. [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35879) on security.stackexchange.

*Note2:* More recent versions of e.g. winzip can use AES to encrypt the contents of zipped files. AFAIK, Python cannot read those.

Comment: I don't think so: [`ZipFile.setpassword(pwd)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword) sets "_pwd_ as default password to extract encrypted files". It doesn't have anything to do with creating password-protected zip files.

Comment: Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you - it was just the 'b', problem solved :-)

Comment: ZipFile library can't set password for a zip file, you have to use pyminizip: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547590/create-password-protected-zip-file-python?rq=1

Comment: If you want to zip multiple in-memory files with a password, use pyzipper.

Comment: As of Python 3.10 [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword) has been updated to show this is a `bytes` object.