# Create password protected zip file?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, zip

I'm using following code to create password protected zip file, from a file uploaded by user, in my Python34 application using `zipFile`. But when I open the zip file from windows, it doesn't ask for the password. I will be using the same password to read zip files from python later on. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
pwdZipFilePath = uploadFilePath + "encryptedZipFiles/"
filePath = uploadFilePath

if not os.path.exists(pwdZipFilePath):        
      os.makedirs(pwdZipFilePath)

#save csv file to a path
fd, filePath = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=source.name, dir=filePath)

with open(filePath, 'wb') as dest:
    shutil.copyfileobj(source, dest)

#convert that csv to zip
fd, pwdZipFilePath = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=source.name + ".zip", dir=pwdZipFilePath)

with zipfile.ZipFile(pwdZipFilePath, 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write(filePath)

    myzip.setpassword(b"tipi")
```

Comment: Can you actually access file files? Or just visualize it? That's a common behavior in zip password protections that you actually can see the files even though it's password protected.

Comment: @user1767754 Yeah I can access file inside zip too. I even opened it. What's the point of setting the password if its just gonna open it anyway?

Comment: @Galen I don't think so. I've checked every related question on this site and still having problems.

Answer (score 15):

The builtin `zipfile` module does not support writing password-encrypted files (only reading). Either you could use `pyminizip`:

```
import pyminizip
pyminizip.compress("dummy.txt", "myzip.zip", "noneshallpass", compression_level)
```

Or, if you're on Windows/msysgit, and agnostic to the format:

```
import os
os.system('tar cz dummy.txt | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -e -k noneshallpass > mypacked.enc')
os.remove('dummy.txt')
os.system('openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -k noneshallpass -in mypacked.enc | tar xz')
```

Comment: I just read `setPassword` and realized after a while that this is for setting before writing.

Comment: @user1767754 you didn't read at all. See answer from [Galen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47547897/87973).

Comment: I actually meant the opposite `before reading` and wanted to emphasize that the first expectation when read is, that you can set the password of zip files, rather then applying a password when reading.

Comment: can't install `pyminizip` on windows.: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 is required. Get it from http://aka.ms/vcpython27"

Comment: Windows 10 22H2 (or at least my machine) has tar in system32, but not openssl.

Answer (score 13):

The [documentation for `zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/zipfile.html) indicates that `ZipFile.setpassword` sets the "default password to extract encrypted files."

At the very top of the documentation: "It supports decryption of encrypted files in ZIP archives, but it currently cannot create an encrypted file."

Edit:
To create a password protected ZIP file, try a package like [pyminizip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyminizip/).

Comment: Okay then how do I create a password protected zip file in python? I have consulted other solutions but they've been no help.

Comment: @TahreemIqbal I would look at a package like [pyminizip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyminizip/).

Comment: okay I'm gonna look into it. Thanks

Comment: I've first thought that he is writing the file and then setting the password, but just realized shockingly that setpassword is kind of lame. But in some book references `python in a nutshell` they are showing how they use `setpassword` to protect against dictionary attacks.

Comment: The documentation for `zipfile` says:  'It supports decryption of encrypted files in ZIP archives, but it currently cannot create an encrypted file. Decryption is extremely slow as it is implemented in native Python rather than C.'  
- Is this module fit for purpose?

Comment: pyminizip doesn't work with in-memory files. If you need in-memory functionality, use pyzipper.