# Python - Opening a Password Protected CSV to read/write

Tags: python, csv, passwords, password-protection

I have been using python for only about two months so I am still quite new to coding.

Recently, in work, I wrote a code which opens an existing CSV file, performs a few operations and spits out a new CSV file.  That bit I am happy with.

But what I want to know is what can  I do in terms of securing the document and still running the code to open it?  For example, I want to password protect this CSV file but want to prompt the user for the password which will be the only way to open/read the file.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You will need to store an encrypted file and decrypt it  on the fly while processing.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV file is simply a formatted text (.txt) file.   So to protect the file there are a few approaches.

1. Save CSV file then change permissions on it using OS commands - [Password Protecting Excel file using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122496/password-protecting-excel-file-using-python)
2. zip the csv file with password.  Unfortunately, "The builtin `zipfile` module does not support writing password-encrypted files (only reading). Either you could use pyminizip.  Refer to [Create password protected zip file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547590/create-password-protected-zip-file-python)