# Password Protection to the file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, azure-blob-storage

I am currently reading file from azure blob storage and sending email. I would like to add password protection to the attachment.
below is my current code which is sending an email with the attachment

```
import base64
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import (Mail, Attachment, FileContent, FileName, FileType)
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

# mail details
to = To_address
from_email = From_Address
subject = Subject
content = '''
Test Content'''


# create mail object
message = Mail(
from_email = from_email,
to_emails = to,
subject = subject,
html_content = content
)

# read the content from azure blob storage
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=Blob_Storage_Account, account_key=account_key)
## read the content inside blob
# read export file
export_file_data = blob_service.get_blob_to_bytes(Blob_Container, export_file_name)
export_file_mail_content = export_file_data.content


# create export file attachement
export_file_encoded = base64.b64encode(export_file_mail_content).decode()
export_file_attachment = Attachment()
export_file_attachment.file_content = FileContent(export_file_encoded)
export_file_attachment.file_type = FileType('application/txt')
export_file_attachment.file_name = FileName(export_file_name.split('/')[-1])
message.add_attachment(export_file_attachment)


# send mail with above attachment
try:
mail = SendGridAPIClient(send_grid_api_key)
response = mail.send(message)
except Exception as e:
print(str(e))
```

any possibilities here to add password to the file which is located in Azure storage before sending email.

I tried with pyminizip but the same is not supporting to my version 3.6. Is there any suggestion apart from open source module?

Comment: Is your ultimate question "How do I create a password protected zip file"?

Comment: @JonSG yes you are right!

Comment: look through these - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=password+protected+zip+file+python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create password protected zip file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547590/create-password-protected-zip-file-python)

Comment: Yes it will be helpful. Let me try something and get back to you. Thank you so much for your help 

Comment: `code`
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import subprocess, random, os

file = "test.txt"
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?"
zipPass = "".join(random.sample(s,12))
print(zipPass)
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
rc = subprocess.call("zip -P "+zipPass+" "+file+".zip "+file, shell=True, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
`code`

I have used the above code,bu i am not sure where the zip file will get store? can someone guide me please.