# Best way to write df to zip and password protect it?

Tags: python, zip, password-encryption, python-zipfile

I'm trying to find a way to write a df to zip file and add a password to it but I can't figure out how.

I've tried

```
import zipfile
archive_name='test.zip'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name, 'w')
zf.setpassword(b"1234")
```

But it always says the file is in use by another process. And when I check other posts it says this is not the preferred method [zipfile: how to set a password for a Zipfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439979/zipfile-how-to-set-a-password-for-a-zipfile).

I'd like to only use a native library but it seems like there is no native way to do this [Create password protected zip file Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547590/create-password-protected-zip-file-python). Can that really be true?

Comment: following on from above comment, what OS are you on? because that information would influence alternative suggestions.

Comment: My current OS is windows.

Comment: Ok, I recommend using 7zip with subprocess. Other SO answers have a nice explanation of doing that. You have to download 7zip unless you already have it: https://www.7-zip.org/download.html

Comment: Unfortunately I need to deploy this to an environment (still Windows) where I can't download/install external libraries. Is there any way to do this with os commands via python at least and not 7zip?

Comment: I haven't seen anything without downloading libraries be they from pip or on the OS :/